# MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core) on testing

Tags: flutter, dart

my code of tests which doesn't work and I have an exception: No implementation found for method Firebase#initializeCore on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_core , and I don't know how to fix it , please help

```
void main() async {
  IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  group('end-to-end test', () {
    testWidgets('test',
            (WidgetTester tester) async {
              tester.binding.scheduleWarmUpFrame();
          await app.main();
          await tester.pumpAndSettle();
          expect(find.text('Login Page'), findsOneWidget);
        });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To Solve Flutter Error: MissingPluginException No implementation found for Method This issue is caused when you just add the plugin and then get dependencies and just hot reload OR hot restart your flutter app. Hot restart or hot reload is not enough to trigger the injection of plugin dependencies. You just have to close Or stop your app and then execute flutter run.

Comment: not in all cases. This error has many faces.